# Designing a simple app for OSX, what to use?

Tags: macos

Heres my problem, I'm web developer and I have a web based script(PHP/CURL/HTML/JS) that gets latest threads from forums with job listings, however right now I have it email me when a new one is made, what I'd like to have is some sort of an app, basic idea would be a browser type app, where it would load in the url, and then html/css would do the rest, refresh every X seconds, play sound if there is a new thread, etc. (however I don't want to just have a tab open, I'd liek it to be a seperate app, I know this is rather easy in VB on windows)

What language would this be coded in and does anyone have any starting points? I have basic experience in VB, but thats about it as far as programming software languages.

Eventually I'd like to make this into an API with the program requesting XML from server and then style it from there, as well as functions such as contact the thread poster etc(but this will require a lot more experience from my end in order to design the functions that could call to the server with all of the parameters etc)

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: I know, it's not the best answer, but can you try: http://fluidapp.com ?

Comment: Maybe check out MonoDevelop?  http://monodevelop.com/

Comment: Native applications for Mac OS X are built on the Cocoa framework with the Objective-C programming language - start at https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac. If you need or want to use C#, you'll have to use a solution like [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) to be able to compile your programs for non-Windows platforms.

Comment: This seems to be more of a conceptual question rather than a programming question or one appropriate for [so].  Also, why did you tag this as c# (a very non-osx technology)?

Comment: Got c# confusecd with Objective-C, been a while since I opened xcode, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using XCode and [Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594) given that you are targeting OS X. This should be rather simple using the [WebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). See here for a [tutorial](http://www.reecefowell.com/2011/04/06/using-webview-in-xcode-4-0-with-objective-c/).

Answer (score 1):

The standard language for use on OS X is objective-c.  However this has quite a steep learning curve.  It is possible to use C# on OS X using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler), but I have no experience with that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [RealStudio](http://realsoftware.com/realstudio/). It's very easy to use and should be familiar, given your VB experience.